# Accessing attr_accessor attributes with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attr-accessor

below question is about selecting the attributes enabled by "attr_accessor" for an object. Example:

```
class Openhour < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :shop    
  attr_accessor :monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday

end
```

This allows me to

```
week = Openhour.new
week.monday = "Open"
week.tuesday = "Closed"
```

My question: How can I select the attr_accessors by using a variable from a loop? In below case I would use `dayname` to select the `attr_accessor`.

```
@schedules.each do |schedule|
   %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday).each_with_index do |dayname,dayname_index|

      week.dayname = schedule.day == dayname_index ? "Open" : "Closed"

   end
end
```

This, however, would result in

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `dayname' for #<Model>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe use an array of symbols `[:monday,... ]` then in your block `week.send(dayname) = ...`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 You canot use it like this `week.send(dayname)` return `String`. If you need to modify value you must to send it inside send method `week.send("#{dayname}=", ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
 week.send("#{dayname}=", schedule.day == dayname_index ? "Open" : "Closed")
```

Or you can work with it like `instance_variables`

```
week.instance_variable_set("@#{dayname}", schedule.day == dayname_index ? "Open" : "Closed")
```